# How and when is static linking performed (MinGW)?

Tags: c++, static, linker, mingw, fortran

I had a lot of pain linking a C++ application to another C++ library with Fortran90 dependencies (MinGW, TDM g++ and gfortran). I either have to use gfortran for linking or the application crashes on startup (in global constructors keyed to __cxa_get_globals_fast). However this is not acceptable, I would like to use g++ for linking (Qt GUI).

It seems to me that the dependencies of the libraries cannot be linked statically with gcc, **linking is only performed when** `main()` **is available. Why?**

I guess partly because code for certain initializations have to be inserted before main().

**Why is it that the statically linked application needs DLL-s**, such as mingwm10.dll or pthreadGCE2.dll at runtime? Why can't these be statically linked?

**UPDATE:** I just found these websites:
http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sol-static.txt
http://www.iecc.com/linker/

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between linking with gfortran and using ld/gcc/g++ to link is that gfortran links the standard fortran libraries by default, whereas with another linker you will need to manually specify the libraries to link.  I wasn't able to find them with a quick search, but it should be along the lines of -lgfortran.

Also, gfortran has some specific [instructions for initialisation routines](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Non_002dFortran-Main-Program.html#Non_002dFortran-Main-Program) that need to be called for certain fortran intrinsics to work if your main program is not written in fortran.  If you haven't called these routines then this might cause a crash.

Comment: Are you referring to this? Non-Fortran Main Program: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Non_002dFortran-Main-Program.html Here is the backtrace of my application:
#0  0x00777520 in global constructors keyed to __cxa_get_globals_fast ()
#1  0x0077ef87 in __do_global_ctors ()
#2  0x0040122a in __mingw_CRTStartup ()
#3  0x00401298 in mainCRTStartup ()

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that the statically linked application needs DLL-s, such as mingwm10.dll or pthreadGCE2.dll at runtime? Why can't these be statically linked?

They can, but static library versions are not provided due to the fundamental advantage of dynamic libraries: bugs can be fixed without rebuilding the executables.

Comment: Could you please tell me how these can be linked statically? Should I build my own static library from source?

Comment: Just have the `.lib` variant in the `libpath` and they will be used.  You would have to build them yourself though.